# How to print the time in a loop in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I basically want to print the time at the start of each loop to a log.

I tried this, but no luck:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,100) DO (
echo Loop Started: %date% - %time%  
echo Loop Started: !date! - !time!  
echo Loop Started: !%date%! - !%time%!  
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
)
```

Never use batch, so not sure where to go next.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use `setlocal` or `cmd /v` to enable delayed expansion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setlocal` to turn on delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,100) DO (
echo Loop Started: !date! - !time!  
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > NUL
)
```

Comment: You should put the setlocal before the loop.  There's no reason to call it on every iteration, especially since setlocal allocates a couple kb per call to duplicate the environment block.  Not really significant for 100 iterations, but could be a problem for 100k+.

Comment: Putting it in the loop was accidental. That's clearly a big deal and a good catch.